# Storing Images of a Java based REST service running on Heroku

Tags: java, postgresql, rest, heroku, amazon-web-services

I am currently developing my first Java based RESTful service that should be run on [Heroku](http://heroku.com). This service manages some objects that have associated images. As Heroku is not able to store this images (apart from storing them in a database), I thought of using an external [Content Delivery Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (*CDN*) like [Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). My first attempt to implement this would be as followed:

1. Encode the image ([base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)) on the client side.
2. Send the encoded image encapsulated in [Json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation) to the server side.
3. Decode the image on the server side.
4. Process the image (scale, create thumbnails, etc.).
5. Store the image in Amazon's CloudFront using the [AWS SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) for Java.
6. Store a link to the image with the associated object in a [postgreSQL database](http://www.postgresql.org/).

Now my question is, if this is the way to go, or if there is a better way to do this and if [this GitHub project](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-java-sample/) is a good point to start. If this helps to give an answer - the images are used within desktop and mobile as well as in web-applications.

Comment: Depending on image size, you could also just store the images directly in PostgreSQL as `bytea` fields or using `pg_largeobject`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I know that this is possible, but Dynos are not that cheap and wasting their computing power for content delivery is not a good idea. Furthermore I have to handle many images and storing images in a database is in most cases also not a good idea. So I am looking for a solution that utilizes a CDN.

Comment: Perfectly sensible and well reasoned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Store the image in Amazon's CloudFront using the AWS SDK for Java.

Er, CloudFront doesn't store things, it caches things. If you want it stored, you need to put the image on S3 and pay for it every month.

> Encode the image (base64) on the client side

Er, why? Just do a PUT or multipart-mime POST, and send the file as bytes.

> Send the encoded image encapsulated in Json to the server side

Again, there's no reason to encode it, you can send the metadata + data in the same POST easily without encoding.

> Store a like to the image with the associated object in a postgreSQL database

Storing images in a database is an anti-pattern.  It makes the database harder to backup, slower to query, etc. Generally, you want to put the image in S3, and store the path in the database.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So as I understand, it is the way to go, I just have to forget about this en- and decoding stuff. `Storing images in a database is an anti-pattern.` Yeah, I know, this is a typo in my post. It should have been `link` not `like` in point six. I already said the same in a comment to Craig Ringer above. :-D

Comment: Following your tips, I was able to write a simple uploader, that takes the given InputStream (no base64 encoding), scales the given image and puts it into a Amazon S3 bucket. Thanks!